# How to be aware if question edited?

Tags: discussion, support

Consider one posted question then I answered &/or commented on that question.

Now if Question is **edited** completely/partially then my answer &/or comment may be totally/partially **wrong according to edited question**.

So, How to get notify if question edited on which I answered &/or commented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following possibilities of alternative solution can be considered:

1. If your answer is **not suitable** or **wrong** than visitors may **replay you by commenting or downvoting**. Also same for your comment (Answer is important but comment are not considered much important)
2. You can **favorite** that question and later filter by favorite tab from your profile:
   [image: screen1]
3. If you concern about or want to get **feed** for a question then you can subscribe for "**question feed**" from bottom-right side of page as follows:

   [image: screen2]

---

Hope this helps to be aware by filtering/grepping!

Answer (score 5):

There is actually no way of notifying repliers about changes in original post, except comments. So, if you want to get notifications about changes even if the author doesn't care about notifying those trying to help him, you should subscribe to that "topic" (i.e. make it favorite).

And, if the answer is wrong, somebody certainly will notify you either by downvoting or by telling what's wrong.